# How to track/find long running processes using Django?

Tags: django, cherokee

I'm using Cherokee(uwsgi) with Django and my timeouts are ridiculous(according to Cherokee). How can I track down what pages are causing these timeouts?

Answer (score 0):

Configure uWSGI without the Cherokee wizard (as a remote source). And study its logs.
They report the time taken by each request and all the disconnections/timeout.

Use TCP sockets so you can get listen queue debug (it will warn you if the number of uWSGI workers is not enough)